# JavaScript: Get arguments[-1]?

Tags: javascript, events, dom, mouse

Is it possible to add a negative value to the key of the arguments object to fetch the current event?

Example:

```
function getMouse(x, y) {
  return new Array(arguments[-1].pageX + x, arguments[-1].pageY + y);
}
```

Comment: Well do you have any suggestions for an alternative approach?

Comment: Pass the event as another argument to the function.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do? How about `arguments.pop()`

Comment: Oh, I think I get it, you're calling that function from inside an event handler, and you're expecting the event to be passed automatically, which it isn't when you call the function that way, you have to do what @Barmar suggests, passing the event as well.

Comment: To get the mouse position you have to get the current event (in some browsers at least), the problem is, that the parameter that holds that event is occupied.

Comment: If you're calling `getMouse` from an event handler, it receives an `event` argument. You can pass this as an argument to `getMouse`, and then access its properties.

Comment: @adeneo Exactly. Is there not another way? This seems like a rather "dirty" solution?

Comment: Nope, the event is only passed when referencing a function, as then the arguments are passed automagically, when calling the function you have to add the event as an argument, no other way to do that.